# How do I 'spam' an url via python?

Tags: python, selenium, http, python-requests, request

I'd want to make a script that automatically sends alot of requests to a URL via Python.
Example link: https://page-views.glitch.me/badge?page_id=page.id

I've tried selenium but thats very slow.

Comment: For a basic load test like that, I recommend [apache bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html). Works great for non-apache web servers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip install requests

```
import requests

for i in range(100): # Or whatever amount of requests you wish to send
    requests.get("https://page-views.glitch.me/badge?page_id=page.id")
```

Or if you really wanted to hammer the address you could use multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests

def my_func(x):
    for i in range(x): 
        print(requests.get("https://page-views.glitch.me/badge?page_id=page.id"))

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    pool.map(my_func, range(0, 100))
if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: Just improved it there for you

Comment: Can you please explain the codeblock within `main()`?

Comment: Sure.. The pool is a pool of multiprocessing processes. in this case it will be the amount of cpus available to it. Say for example that number of processes is 8. So 8 processes will execute the map function concurrently on my_func. So in total there would be in this case 800 requests in total sent to the web address in the same time 100 would be sent in the first example  I gave you.. That is if the cpu_count is 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can send send multiple `get()` requests in a loop as follows:

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.get(https://page-views.glitch.me/badge?page_id=page.id)
```

Comment: yes, i have tried this but it was still very slow. But another person has sent a version with requests which is more faster. but thank you for respondig anyway!

Comment: @JohnJain As long as [tag:selenium] is tagged I'm up to offer the best possible help :)